Why does a dict_keys object ignore the order in checking equality, but not the dict_values object?
Code Snippet
Code:
from collections import Counter

s1 = "yxxx"
s2 = "xyyy"

map1 = Counter(s1)
map2 = Counter(s2)

print(map1.keys())
print(map2.keys())

print("Are map1's keys and map2's keys equal:", map1.keys() == map2.keys())

print()
print(map1.values())
print(map2.values())
print("Are map1's values and map2's values equal:", map1.values() == map2.values())
print("Are SORTED map1's values and map2's values equal:", sorted(map1.values()) == sorted(map2.values()))

Results:
dict_keys(['y', 'x'])
dict_keys(['x', 'y'])
Are map1's keys and map2's keys equal: True

dict_values([1, 3])
dict_values([1, 3])
Are map1's values and map2's values equal: False
Are SORTED map1's values and map2's values equal: True

I understand that the return type of keys() function similar to a set-like view, so when evaluating equality the order wouldn't matter, but how about values()? Even though the values in map1 and map2 are the same, the value returned is still False. But why does calling sorted() return True although the order of the values remain unchanged?

Don't post code as screenshots. There's no reason to not include it in the question

Because {'a': 1, 'b': 2} is not equivalent to {'b': 1, 'a': 2}. They have the same set of values, and in the same order, but it's just a coincidence.

@Barmar, I specifically compare the returned values from keys() and values(), so I'm wondering why it isn't mutually exclusive.

The order of keys is generally irrelevant, so it's compared without regard to order. But values are only equivalent if each value is associated with the same key. It makes little sense to compare values by themselves.

You could always convert the values to a list or set if you want to compare them that way.

"Do these two dictionaries have the same keys?" is a common thing to ask, and keys are required to be hashable already so set operations are trivial. "Do these two dictionaries have the same values, irrespective of which keys they correspond with?" isn't (and if you do care about corresponding keys that's just dictionary equality), plus the values may not be hashable so the comparison would be much less efficient.

Does calling sorted "lose" the values' association with the keys then? I'm confused why calling sorted will work if they're attached by their keys for equality

sorted(x.values()) converts the values to a list. There's no association with the keys any more.

Dict values view comparison doesn't look at order. In fact, it doesn't even look at the values. In fact, it doesn't even look at the dict in any way!
Trying to implement values view comparison as order-insensitive would have had major efficiency issues, as values aren't required to be comparable or hashable. Trying to implement values view comparison as caring about order would have been inconsistent and not very useful, especially back when these views were first implemented, when dicts didn't preserve order.
Instead, values views don't implement an == comparison. Dict values views just inherit object.__eq__. Two dict values views are equal if and only if they are, in fact, the exact same object. So you get results like
In [1]: x = {}

In [2]: x.values() == x.values()
Out[2]: False

In [3]: y = x.values()

In [4]: y == y
Out[4]: True

Your sorted calls produce lists, not dict values views. Lists perform == comparisons differently.

When you compare two dictionaries, it only checks that the keys/value pairs are the same, the order is irrelevant (prior to Python 3.7 dictionaries didn't even preserve order, so it didn't make sense to refer to their order).
So when testing whether two dictionaries have the same keys, the same logic implies that the order of keys is irrelevant.
But that logic does not extend to values, because values are only equivalent if each they're associated with corresponding keys.
If in your application you just want to compare the values regardless of the keys and order, you can do that with your sorted(d.values()) comparison. That converts the values to a list and puts them in consistent order, ignoring the keys. This is an unusual use case, so it's not the default behavior.

I understand that your question is highly logical.
But there is also another logic that dictionary is meant to mention which key refers to which value. That is it focuses on key, value pair but not the sequence(index). list and tuple are the only representations of sequence and value.
Both the logic are correct. So  According to me, apart from logic, a programming language should have all the options we want to execute. For instance if you want to check the sequence as well, you can any way use..
print(list(map1.keys()) == list(map2.keys())) #Output: False

But if you try..
print(list(map1.values()) == list(map2.values())) #Output: True

Because the output is [1,3] in both the list(map1.values() and list(map1.values(). Again it is logical.
Let us assume why dict should not focus on the sequence.
When you're declaring variables say a=5; b=3, If you change the order and declare b=3; a=5, Is it wrong? When the sequence doesn't matter here, thse sequence should not matter in dict as well. Again, It is logical.
Only thing, you should be able to do whatever you want to do in a good programming language. That's it.
print(map1==map2) #Output: False
print(map1.keys() == map2.keys()) #Output: True
print(map1.values() == map2.values()) #Output: False
print(list(map1.keys()) == list(map2.keys())) #Output: False
print(list(map1.values()) == list(map2.values())) #Output: True

Note: In plain english, a list refers also to the sequence in which the things are listed. So, In the nomenclature itself, there is a logic. 
